# How can I put data is parsed from excel to model?

Tags: python, django, excel

I parsed excel and get row data in list. It is like

```
[empty:'', text:’1', text:’1’, text:’40’, text:'']
[empty:'', text:’2’, text:’5’, text:’23’, text:’●’]
[empty:'', text:’3’, text:’9’, text:’52’, text:'']
```

My excel(data.xlsx) is
[image: excel]

so list output is ok.Now I wanna put this list to model(User).
User model in models.py is

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    man = models.BooleanField()
```

The last code of `man = models.BooleanField()` means man or woman,if ’●’ in excel,it means the user is man and true wanna be put in man variable.
Now views.py is

```
    #coding:utf-8
    from django.shortcuts import render
    import xlrd

    book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/data.xlsx')
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

    for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
        row = sheet.row(row_index)  
        print(row) 
  # I had to add codes connect controller & model
```

I do not know how to send these list data to model and model has these data.Strictly speaking,I wanna write these list data to sqlite3.Is this code

```
import app.models
for x in row:
  User.user_id = row[1]
  User.name_id = row[2]
  User.age = row[3]
  User.man = row[4]
```

good way to write model?(or is it wrong way?)
Is there other more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the whole row and columns thing right, this should work:

```
for row in rows:
  # if the man column is not empty, we assume it's a male:
  is_man = row[4] != ""
  user = User(user_id=row[1], name_id=row[2], age=row[3], man=is_man)
  user.save()
```

Comment: thx ur comments.I wrote ur codes,but error  happens like
from .models import User
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import .
How can I fix this?

Comment: try removing the import and use your IDE to add the import automatically.

Comment: thx ur comments.I removed the import and used my IDE to import it,but now  error happens     
from app.models import User
ImportError: No module named 'app'     .However,models.py & views.py are in app(it is child app) folder,so I really cannot understand why No module named 'app' error happens.How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you followed any Django tutorial when setting your project up? has it eve worked, because this seems like a whole new question.